# Passing ng-click/ng-submit promise to directive

Tags: angularjs

Basically, I created a directive that passes a promise to the link function from ng-click and and detects when the promise is done so that I can attach a class to it.

Example:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($parse) {
    return {
         restrict: 'A',
         scope: {
            ng-click: '&'
         },
         link: function(scope) {
            var d = $parse(scope.ngClick);

            element.on('click', function(event) {
                d().then(function() {
                    element.addClass(attrs.myDirective);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

<element ng-click="promise();" my-directive="class"></element>

//controller function
$scope.promise = function() {
    return promise().then(function() {});
}
```

It is doing what I want except that the controller function is getting called three times. I would really like to just use require: '^ngClick' here but since the ngClick directive does not have any controllers, I can't do that. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added event.preventDefault() to the event.on('click') function in the link of my directive:

```
element.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    d().then(function() {
        element.addClass(attrs.myDirective);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hi! I'd like to do business logic on my controller that's why I needed ng-click.